# How to style links for modal boxes (prettyPhoto)

Tags: css, css-selectors, prettyphoto

I am trying to use the standard CSS styling for text links that open modal boxes...specifically prettyPhoto. I would like the link color to change to the a:visited color after it is clicked. It's not working, the link stays the same color. Here's my CSS:

```
a:link {color: #117D9A;}
a:visited {color: #555555;text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
a:active {color: #bfbfbf;}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does prettyPhoto have a css file that is overriding your styles?

Comment: Thanks for the response! No...prettyPhoto CSS does not include anchor tags. Hover is working fine. Just not visited or active. I've even tried !important property. Nothing.

Comment: Do you have a live example you could show?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry I didn't provide that in the beginning. http://www.reneepearson.com/01video_players/test.php

Comment: My guess is that the browser isn't interpreting that the link has been 'visited' because it's not leaving the page. A javascript solution would be to add a class when the link is clicked, and add the style to that class.

Comment: Thanks again, Sean. I guessed that was the problem, too. Unfortunately, I'm not a javascript coder. I'll search Google to see what I can find in the way of examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update! I found the javascript to do what you suggested...it was pretty easy and the change in class worked. But when the page is refreshed it goes back to the original link color.

Comment: Try to change the doctype

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

To 

<!DOCTYPE html>